# Backbone AMD with requireJs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, amd

From the Logs, Backbone now registers itself for AMD (Require.js) Since v1.1.1.

Great, So I try to do the same for a module but there is something I don't understand.

If we look at [section 4 of annotated sources](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-4) the sources, The module doesn't return the global Backbone.

No need shim and window.Backbone is available. But How Backbone can not be undefined ?

// Definition Backbone Module

```
define(['underscore', 'jquery', 'exports'], function(_, $, exports) {
   root.Backbone = factory(root, exports, _, $);
});
```

// Require Backbone module

```
require(['backbone'], function (Backbone) {
  Backbone // is not undefined ?
});
```

---

// Modal module Definition

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
   root.Modal = factory(root, {}, $);
});
```

// Require Modal module

```
require(['modal'], function (Modal) {
   Modal // undefined
});
```

---

Into my module (using the same structure), When I require my module, I got `undefined` if I don't return anything.

I have to return root.Modal in order to make it work. `return root.Modal = factory(root, {}, $);`

The main question is "**How a module can be required while the module doesn't return anything ?** "

I have missing something on requireJS, but I don't find it.

http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-4

Comment: never, never use window.Backbone, and if it's registered like an AMD module you don't need to "shim", your file is named like "backbone.js"?

Comment: I don't use window.Backbone :)
Do you speak of my module file ? I have modal.js with the same file structure.

Comment: if you are calling for "backbone" inside your module you've to have the "backbone.js" file unless if you've mapped before this name...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in question is this:

```
define(['underscore', 'jquery', 'exports'], function(_, $, exports) {
    root.Backbone = factory(root, exports, _, $);
});
```

Note now `factory` is called with `exports` as the 2nd parameter. The factory function is going to export Backbone's methods by setting fields on this object. This is why when you require Backbone, you get a useful value and not `undefined` or garbage.

This reason this works is that RequireJS supports defining a module by returning a value from the factory function you give to `define`, so you can do this:

```
define(function () {
    return {
        foo: function () { ... }
    };
});
```

But it supports also other means to do this, like for instance:

```
define(['exports'], function (exports) {
    exports.foo = function () { ... };
});
```

In the code above the module named `exports` in the list of dependencies is a special (and reserved) module name which means "give me an object on which I can set fields to export values".
Backbone uses this 2nd way of exporting a value.